# Call JQuery function From Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am populating dropdown list using JQuery. whenever i selected any item from that dropdown (i.e Drop down selected index change) i want to run an another JQuery Function... Here is my controller..

```
   public ActionResult PopulateTest(string Id)
    {
      // Here i want to call the JQuery function
        return PartialView("Details");
    }
```

and my JQuery Function...

```
 $(function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("HidStatus").value;
    var b = parseInt(a);
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: b,
        max: 100
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this might be helpful to you..just try this...

```
 public ActionResult PopulateTest(string Id)
{
  // Here i want to call the JQuery function
    page << "foo()" // call your function here after "<<"
  or you can use call method
    page.call:foo();
    return PartialView("Details");
}
```

here is reference of call method [call](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M000555)

Comment: another way to express thanks is just simply vote up.:)  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/