# Call jQuery function from controller in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I call a jQuery function from a MVC controller?

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756194/call-jquery-function-from-controller) but I am not sure what "page" means here.

Comment: I don't think your linked post even relates to MVC. The link in the accepted answer goes to a (defunct) Ruby on Rails documentation.

Comment: That is just an example. My scenario is MVC.

Comment: Not directly but you can try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049817/in-asp-net-mvc-all-possible-ways-to-call-controller-action-method-from-a-razor  in `success` callback

Answer (score 1):

Something strange about *page* for me too. I think that you can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library for your purpose. It allows to call javascript functions from client side inside controller and much much more cool things.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call js functions from mvc controller. But you can send messages from server side to client side that will rise events via [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling) technology.